# php pdo mssql driver on centos

Tags: sql-server, php, centos, drivers, pdo

How do I install PHP PDO Mssql Driver on Centos?

Answer (score 1):

`yum install php-pdo`

there is also a php 5.3 version, if you have that version of php installed php53-pdo, but don't install that otherwise as the upgrade breaks loads of stuff.

there is a php-mssql module as well which might be handy.

Answer (score 0):

php has a sybase driver that can connect mssql server, also you can use odbc to connect.

modules are `php5-sybase` and `php5-odbc`

in ubuntu I can install them using

```
 sudo apt-get install php5-odbc php5-sybase
```

in red-hat it should alike, using yum.